# if error or blank, highlight cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an excel file where row AP has a list of emails. This list of emails is generated by a `VLOOKUP` from another file. I want to highlight cell H4 if my range in column AP has a blank or error message in one of the cells. This formula should do the trick but i don't know where I am going wrong.

`{=IF(ISNA(AP7:AP22),"Error column AP","Yes")}`

I could also use a Macro if easier.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands your formula only flags up if there is a #N/A error, you need to modify the formula to find blanks also.

```
{=IF(SUM(IF(ISNA(AP7:AP22),1,IF(AP7:AP22="",1,0)))>0,"Error column AP","Yes")}
```

Comment: It works if one of the cells is blank but not when the VBA returns an #N/A. Could be something wrong with the format? can't see what's wrong..

Comment: @Abigal what do you mean by "when the VBA returns an #N/A"? The `IsNA` function tests for an *actual Error type*, which is not the same as a string literal. Can you provide sample of the code which returns #N/A from VBA?

Comment: Sorry, I meant excel formula not VBA. My bad. Apologies

Comment: It seems the #N/A error doesn't play nicely with blank, I've edited the post with an amended solution that definitely works, hopefully someone can provide a more elegant solution.